# Android Movable Line Chart

Tags: android, android-canvas, mpandroidchart, android-graphview

I want to implement draggable line chart for android.

• [This is exactly i want to](http://www.mediafire.com/view/3w9eo2zz2elfqbr/del.gif)

I have referred many charts library like mpandroid, android-plot, hz-graphview among all line charts are static.

P.S I'm not asking anyone to implement this all i need is guidelines or any open source library will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A library is now available with the same feature mentioned.

[source](https://github.com/appsthatmatter/GraphView)

Achieved same functionality with this library with minor modification.

Comment: how did you implement it with minor modification? I also need a curves like graph same as google snapseed app for image editing. What i want is to show line graph and then drag when user taps on the point on line graph

Comment: I tried to achieve this change using inheritance, it's not minor at all. And I'm stucked to the state where I cannot modify the dataset points, so I think I'll need to fork the library

Comment: @Livio exactly, you need to do custom modification for the similar requirement.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to start with trying out [this sample](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html) from Android developers-site to get started with drawing in canvas if you haven't done so before. Then start to modify the sample to use `onTouchEvent` for dragging the objects, and take it from there.

Read more: [Drag Shape On Canvas in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094575/drag-shape-on-canvas-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

It seems MPAndroidChart has dragging feature. Check it out. BTW I haven't tried it yet.
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/README.md

Comment: It is drag-able whole graph left to right but not x,y coordinates.